# Can't open terminal - java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY"

Tags: java, android, terminal

I try to open the terminal in android studio but every time I press on it, it says " java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY". How to fix this?

Comment: Try this: https://forum.xda-developers.com/tools/android-studio/bug-android-studio-terminal-wont-start-t3128098

Comment: I have seen the second link. The problem is that there is no studio64.exe file in my PC.

Comment: It must have some similar file, if the Android Studio is installed in your machine. Search in /bin folder of the program.

Comment: This is my /bin folder. Which one is that? https://ibb.co/fT1rkQ

Comment: You told that there was no studio64.exe on your PC. I just saw it now on the /bin folder! Just enable file types extension in the folder and you will see the ".exe"...

Comment: Now it says "This app can't run on your PC". My computer runs on 32bit windows 10. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Yes. Try to download a 32bits installer, remove this 64bits program and install the other.

Comment: I did so. I clicked on  studio.exe then checked "run as an administrator". But it didn't solve my problem. I still can't open the terminal :/

Comment: Did you install a 32bits program and the same error continues?

Comment: Yes :( This solution didn't work for me .

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by open Settings>Tool>Terminal, I found that the shell path is invalid(Maybe this is caused by I update the github version)，So I choose another path that lie in another folder which name is git-cmd.exe