# java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY

Tags: android

In android studio when I click on terminal--> '+' button new terminal does not open

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't open terminal - java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45258211/cant-open-terminal-java-io-ioexception-couldnt-create-pty)

Comment: i have tried this one also but it didn't worked. i think  file has deleted from system.

Comment: if it was deleted, then you have to obviously restore it. Easiest is to reinstall Android Studio.

Comment: but that is last option,i find some other way to fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to `File -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal` and change Shell path based on the the installed git version.

for 64bit:
`"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" -login -i`

for 32bit:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" -login -i`

Don't forget the quotes around the command.

Comment: Use `cmd.exe` as shell path then.

Comment: actually my anti virus has expired. so some file deleted automatically like adb.exe , and other '.exe' file also.

Comment: I faced the same problem. Getting into `File -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal` i noticed that Debian WSL did updated automatically, so i had to put the new folder/path

Answer (score 5):

If it doesn't work,you may set the Start directory wrong:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue can arise due to various reasons. I faced the same issue and none of the above steps worked for me. 
Then I checked the IntelliJ logs **C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\.IntelliJIdea2018.2\system\log**. This will give you the exact reason for the problem.

For me issue was Windows update caused some Dll Permission issue. hence ** I did a system restore** to a time before the time I started facing this issue and the problem is fixed